# How to access parse cloud functions using arduino?

Tags: arduino-yun

I have created rest service using .js file on Parse.com.
I want to access cloud function from arduino.

i tried this

client.get(https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/functions/hello");

i am getting error "Method not allowed".

Solution :
Somehow i got the answer which is as follows.I hope it will help others.

```
 ParseCloudFunction cloudFunction;
 cloudFunction.setFunctionName(function_name);  //string ("hello")
 cloudFunction.add("light_sensor", light); //pass parameter to cloud

 ParseResponse response = cloudFunction.send();
 Serial.println(response.getJSONBody());
```

Comment: What is a rest service?

Comment: REST api i have written on Parse side that i want to access from Arduino sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read api of Parse and there i got the class to call cloud function from 
Arduino.I hope it will help others.

```
 ParseCloudFunction cloudFunction;
 cloudFunction.setFunctionName(fnname); //String ("hello")
 cloudFunction.add("light_sensor", 139); //parameter

 ParseResponse response = cloudFunction.send();
 Serial.println(response.getJSONBody());
```